# SQL CLR stored Procedure to query active directory

Tags: sql-server-2005, clr

I need to obtain some information from the users in the database that is stored on Active Directory, I've a simple function to do this:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ANYGIVENDOMAIN"))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
    {
        adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=jdoe)";                  
        SearchResult adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(adSearchResult.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(adSearchResult.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(adSearchResult.Properties["objectSid"][0].ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(adSearchResult.Properties["description"][0].ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(adSearchResult.Properties["objectGUID"][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Running from a WinForm do as I want, but in the SQL Server Project Type I can't add the namespace System.DirectoryServices to the references.

Anyone knows why ?

Regards

JE

Comment: Just as an aside - if I were you, I'd make sure to **check** whether a given property is present or not; `if(adSearchResult.Properties["..."] != null) ....  ` because otherwise, you'll most certainly will get some NULL pointer exceptions sooner or later....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx)

> Unsupported libraries can still be
>   called from your managed stored
>   procedures, triggers, user-defined
>   functions, user-defined types, and
>   user-defined aggregates. The
>   unsupported library must first be
>   registered in the SQL Server database,
>   using the CREATE ASSEMBLY statement,
>   before it can be used in your code.
>   Any unsupported library that is
>   registered and run on the server
>   should be reviewed and tested for
>   security and reliability.
>
> For example, the
>   System.DirectoryServices namespace is
>   not supported. You must register the
>   System.DirectoryServices.dll assembly
>   with UNSAFE permissions before you can
>   call it from your code. The UNSAFE
>   permission is necessary because
>   classes in the
>   System.DirectoryServices namespace do
>   not meet the requirements for SAFE or
>   EXTERNAL_ACCESS. For more information,
>   see [CLR Integration Programming Model
>   Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx) and [CLR Integration Code
>   Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx).

Comment: Thanks i'm looking into that documentation and seems it's exactly what i need.

Comment: I've done everything needed, now i'm getting this error:
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'GetInformationFromActiveD'
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesPermission, System.DirectoryServices,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed. System.Security.SecurityException:at StoredProcedures.getUserInfoFromActiveDirectory(SqlString userName, SqlString domain, SqlString& description, SqlString& displayName)
Permissions?from winforms it works

Comment: Turns out that i need to make my assembly also unsafe, that makes the trick. So in summary 
1. add assembly for directoryservices as unsafe (Changing trustworthy permissions on the database aswell)
2. add the assembly that uses it also as unsafe
3. Enjoy
Hope this helps someone else.
And Thanks also to Joe by pointing me the right direction. :)